# Verificar com JavaScript um campo Select Multiple se tem valor

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho dois select's multiple como se fossem um De > Para, no "De" eu tenho lista de e-mails vinda de banco com ASP Clássico, eu já consigo passar os e-mails para o select "Para", mas não consigo pegar os emails na função transporte, gostaria da ajuda de vcs se dá pra usar um jeito de pegar esses valores que estão no select Para, segue código abaixo com todo processo.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Mailing</TITLE>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../Estilos/estilos.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="../../../JS/functions.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        function Transporte() {

            var retEmails;
            var objSelecionados = document.frmSelecionaEmail.Selec.value;

            alert("Pegou os e-mails");
            alert(objSelecionados);

            if (objSelecionados != '') {

                for (i = 0; i <= objSelecionados.options.length; i++) {

                    if (objSelecionados.options[i].selected = true) {
                        retEmails = objSelecionados[i].value;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                alert("Nenhum e-mail selecionado.");
            }

            alert(retEmails);

        }
    </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY topmargin="5" leftmargin="0">

    <form name="frmSelecionaEmail" method="post" action="">
        <!--CORPO-->
        <td width="2%" class="subInfoTit"><input type="submit" name="btOk" value="Ok" class="cmd" onclick="return Transporte();" /></td>
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" class="tbllogin">
            <tr>
                <td class="subInfoTit" colspan="2">
                <%if Session("SGALinguagem") = "PT" then %>
                    Lista por E-mail
                <%elseif Session("SGALinguagem") = "ES" then %>
                    Lista por Correo elecrónico
                <%elseif Session("SGALinguagem") = "EN" then %>
                    List by E-mail
                <%end if%>                  
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="21">
                <td colspan="7" width="100%">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" width="45%"><b>
                            <%if Session("SGALinguagem") = "PT" then %>
                                E-mails selecionados
                            <%elseif Session("SGALinguagem") = "ES" then %>
                                Correo electrónico no seleccionados
                            <%elseif Session("SGALinguagem") = "EN" then %>
                                Unselected E-mails
                            <%end if%>
                            </b></td>
                            <td align="center" width="10%"></td>
                            <td align="center" width="45%"><b>
                            <%if Session("SGALinguagem") = "PT" then %>
                                E-mails não selecionados
                            <%elseif Session("SGALinguagem") = "ES" then %>
                                Correo electrónico seleccionados
                            <%elseif Session("SGALinguagem") = "EN" then %>
                                Selected E-mails
                            <%end if%>
                            </b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" width="45%">                         
                                <select name="NSelec" size="8" multiple style="width: 100%;">
                                <%
                                SQL="SELECT Email_Endereco, Email_Nome FROM Email"

                                    Call AbreRS(SQL)
                                    While Not Rs.EOF
                                        'v_Id_Email          = Rs("Id_Email")
                                        'v_Email_Nome        = Rs("Email_Nome")
                                        v_Email_Endereco    = Rs("Email_Endereco")

                                        %>
                                        <option value="<%=v_Email_Endereco%>"><%=v_Email_Endereco%></option>
                                        <%
                                        Rs.MoveNext
                                    Wend
                                    Call FechaRS
                                %>
                                </select>                                   
                            </td>                         
                            <td align="center" width="10%">
                                <input type="button" value=">" name="Ins_Item" style="border: 1px solid #636396;color: #636396;width:30px;cursor:hand;" OnClick="MoveDadosLista('Selec', 'NSelec', false);"><br>
                                <input type="button" value=">>" name="Ins_Todos" style="border: 1px solid #636396;color: #636396;width:30px;cursor:hand;" OnClick="MoveDadosLista('Selec', 'NSelec', true);"><br>
                                <input type="button" value="<<" name="Ret_Todos" style="border: 1px solid #636396;color: #636396;width:30px;cursor:hand;" OnClick="MoveDadosLista('NSelec', 'Selec', true);"><br>
                                <input type="button" value="<" name="Ret_Item" style="border: 1px solid #636396;color: #636396;width:30px;cursor:hand;" OnClick="MoveDadosLista('NSelec', 'Selec', false);">
                            </td>
                            <td align="center" width="45%">
                                <select name="Selec" size="8" multiple style="width: 100%;">

                                </select>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Sei que o campo "Selec", esta vazio no final, mas tem alguma forma de fazer ele verificar?  Pois essa tela ai é uma popup que vai enviar os e-mails para a tela principal num campo Para do meu sistema de mailing, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Tem alguns erros no seu código, como, por exemplo:

```
i <= objSelecionados.options.length
```

Usando o operador `<=` irá extrapolar o número de elementos, resultando em erro. O correto é usar apenas `<` para iterar até o limite da array (*o índice máximo de uma array é igual ao número de itens -1*):

```
i < objSelecionados.options.length
```

Outro erro é o operador de atribuição `=` no `if`. O operador correto é `==`.

Um detalhe é que selecionando o `select` com `document.frmSelecionaEmail.Selec` já é retornado os `option`s, portanto não precisa usar `options[i]`.

Alterei o código transformando a variável `retEmails` em array de forma que os emails selecionados sejam armazenados.

No exemplo abaixo fiz alterações no HTML apenas para ilustração do funcionamento (veja explicações no código):

```js
function Transporte() {

   var retEmails = []; // cria a array
   var objSelect = document.frmSelecionaEmail.Selec; // seleciona o select

   if (objSelect.value) { // verifica se há ao menos 1 item selecionado

      for (i = 0; i < objSelect.length; i++) {
         if (objSelect[i].selected == true) {
            retEmails.push(objSelect[i].value); // adiciona na array apenas os itens selecionados
         }
      }
   } else {
      alert("Nenhum e-mail selecionado.");
   }

   console.clear();
   console.log(retEmails);

}
```

```html
<form name="frmSelecionaEmail" method="post" action="">
     <!--CORPO-->
     <td width="2%" class="subInfoTit"><input type="button" name="btOk" value="Ok" class="cmd" onclick="return Transporte();" /></td>
     <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" class="tbllogin">
         <tr height="21">
             <td colspan="7" width="100%">
                 <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
                     <tr>
                         <td align="center" width="45%">                         
                             <select name="NSelec" size="8" multiple style="width: 100%;">
                             </select>                                   
                         </td>                         
                         <td align="center" width="10%">
                             <input type="button" value=">" name="Ins_Item" style="border: 1px solid #636396;color: #636396;width:30px;cursor:hand;" OnClick="MoveDadosLista('Selec', 'NSelec', false);"><br>
                             <input type="button" value=">>" name="Ins_Todos" style="border: 1px solid #636396;color: #636396;width:30px;cursor:hand;" OnClick="MoveDadosLista('Selec', 'NSelec', true);"><br>
                             <input type="button" value="<<" name="Ret_Todos" style="border: 1px solid #636396;color: #636396;width:30px;cursor:hand;" OnClick="MoveDadosLista('NSelec', 'Selec', true);"><br>
                             <input type="button" value="<" name="Ret_Item" style="border: 1px solid #636396;color: #636396;width:30px;cursor:hand;" OnClick="MoveDadosLista('NSelec', 'Selec', false);">
                         </td>
                         <td align="center" width="45%">
                             <select name="Selec" size="8" multiple style="width: 100%;">
                                  <option value="email1@email.com">email1@email.com</option>
                                  <option value="email2@email.com">email2@email.com</option>
                                  <option value="email3@email.com">email3@email.com</option>

                             </select>
                         </td>

                     </tr>
                 </table>
             </td>
         </tr>

     </table>
 </form>
```